# Power-Automate: Verify if Email Attachment (Excel) has the Same Content as Excel Sheet on SharePoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a flow that is triggered when an email arrives, this periodic email contains an attachment of couple of rows only (most of the time only the headers of the column and one row with data), sometimes the email may be sent with the same data as the previous email, where in SharePoint location there's already a copy of that file from previous emails.

I want to create a condition that compares the newly received attachment with the existing one on SharePoint, if they have the same content then "do nothing", if the attachment contains a different content than the file in SharePoint, then the flow continues and the new attachment is created as a file in SharePoint replacing the old file. (I can't compare 1 row because the two files may have one common row but may have other different rows)

The following is the current flow, I need to put the abovementioned verification before the action 'Create File'

[image]

Is this feasible? If yes, I may need some details.

Many thanks in advance.